# Setting up an effect AudioUnit

Tags: ios, audio, filter, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to write an iOS app that captures sound from the microphone, passes it through a high-pass filter, and does some calculation on the processed sound. Based on Stefan Popp's MicInput (http://www.stefanpopp.de/2011/capture-iphone-microphone/), I'm trying to put an effect audio unit (more specifically, a high-pass filter effect unit) inbetween the input and the output of the I/O Audio Unit. After setting up said AU, it gives me a 10877 error (`kAudioUnitErr_InvalidElement`) when I call `AudioUnitRender(fxAudioUnit, ...)` in the I/O AU's render callback.

**AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI.h**

```
//
//  AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>

@interface AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI : NSObject

@property (readonly) AudioBuffer                        audioBuffer;
@property (readonly) AudioComponentInstance             audioUnit;
@property (readonly) AudioComponentInstance             fxAudioUnit;

...

@end
```

**AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI.m**

```
//
//  AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI.m
//

#import "AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI.h"

@implementation AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI

@synthesize isPlaying = _isPlaying;
@synthesize outputLevelDisplay = _outputLevelDisplay;
@synthesize audioBuffer = _audioBuffer;
@synthesize audioUnit = _audioUnit;
@synthesize fxAudioUnit = _fxAudioUnit;

...

#pragma mark Recording callback

static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                              UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    // the data gets rendered here
    AudioBuffer buffer;

    // a variable where we check the status
    OSStatus status;

    /**
     This is the reference to the object who owns the callback.
     */
    AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI *audioProcessor = (__bridge AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI*) inRefCon;

    /**
     on this point we define the number of channels, which is mono
     for the iphone. the number of frames is usally 512 or 1024.
     */
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2; // sample size
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1; // one channel
    buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 ); // buffer size

    // we put our buffer into a bufferlist array for rendering
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;
```

And on the next `AudioUnitRender` call is where the 10887 error is thrown:

```
    status = AudioUnitRender([audioProcessor fxAudioUnit], ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);
[audioProcessor hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];
```

...

```
// process the bufferlist in the audio processor
    [audioProcessor processBuffer:&bufferList];

    //do some further processing

    // clean up the buffer
    free(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData);

    return noErr;
}

#pragma mark FX AudioUnit render callback
//This just asks for samples to the microphone (I/O AU render)
static OSStatus fxAudioUnitRenderCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                      AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                      const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                      UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                      UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                      AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    OSStatus retorno;

    AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI* audioProcessor = (__bridge AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI*)inRefCon;

    retorno = AudioUnitRender([audioProcessor audioUnit],
                          ioActionFlags,
                          inTimeStamp,
                          inBusNumber,
                          inNumberFrames,
                          ioData);
    [audioProcessor hasError:retorno:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    return retorno;
}

#pragma mark Playback callback

static OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                             AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                             const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                             UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                             UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                             AudioBufferList *ioData) {    

    /**
     This is the reference to the object who owns the callback.
     */
    AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI *audioProcessor = (__bridge AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI*) inRefCon;

    // iterate over incoming stream and copy to output stream
    for (int i=0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++) { 
        AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i];

        // find minimum size
        UInt32 size = min(buffer.mDataByteSize, [audioProcessor audioBuffer].mDataByteSize);

        // copy buffer to audio buffer which gets played after function return
        memcpy(buffer.mData, [audioProcessor audioBuffer].mData, size);

        // set data size
        buffer.mDataByteSize = size; 
    }
    return noErr;
}

#pragma mark - objective-c class methods
-(AudioProcessingWithAudioUnitAPI*)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.isPlaying = NO;
        [self initializeAudio];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initializeAudio
{    
    OSStatus status;

    // We define the audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output; // we want to ouput
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO; // we want in and ouput
    desc.componentFlags = 0; // must be zero
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0; // must be zero
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple; // select provider

    // find the AU component by description
    AudioComponent component = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // create audio unit by component
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(component, &_audioUnit);

    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    // and now for the fx AudioUnit
        desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HighPassFilter;

    // find the AU component by description
    component = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // create audio unit by component
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(component, &_fxAudioUnit);

    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    // define that we want record io on the input bus
    AudioUnitElement inputElement = 1;
    AudioUnitElement outputElement = 0;

    UInt32 flag = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, // use io
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, // scope to input
                              inputElement, // select input bus (1)
                              &flag, // set flag
                              sizeof(flag));
    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    UInt32 anotherFlag = 0;
    // disable output (I don't want to hear back from the device)
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, // use io
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, // scope to output
                              outputElement, // select output bus (0)
                              &anotherFlag, // set flag
                              sizeof(flag));
    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    /* 
     We need to specify our format on which we want to work.
     We use Linear PCM cause its uncompressed and we work on raw data.
     for more informations check.

     We want 16 bits, 2 bytes per packet/frames at 44khz 
     */
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = SAMPLE_RATE;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16; //65536
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;

    // set the format on the output stream
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              inputElement, 
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));

    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    // set the format on the input stream
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              outputElement, 
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));
    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    /**
     We need to define a callback structure which holds
     a pointer to the recordingCallback and a reference to
     the audio processor object
     */
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;

    // set recording callback
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback; // recordingCallback pointer
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;

    // set input callback to recording callback on the input bus
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                              inputElement, 
                              &callbackStruct, 
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));

    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    /*
     We do the same on the output stream to hear what is coming
     from the input stream
     */
    callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;

    // set playbackCallback as callback on our renderer for the output bus
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                              outputElement,
                              &callbackStruct,
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));
    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];



    callbackStruct.inputProc = fxAudioUnitRenderCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;

    // set input callback to input AU
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.fxAudioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                              0, 
                              &callbackStruct, 
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));

    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    // reset flag to 0
    flag = 0;

    /*
     we need to tell the audio unit to allocate the render buffer,
     that we can directly write into it.
     */
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              inputElement,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.fxAudioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              0,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));

    /*
     we set the number of channels to mono and allocate our block size to
     1024 bytes.
     */
    _audioBuffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    _audioBuffer.mDataByteSize = 512 * 2;
    _audioBuffer.mData = malloc( 512 * 2 );

    // Initialize the Audio Unit and cross fingers =)
    status = AudioUnitInitialize(self.fxAudioUnit);
    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    status = AudioUnitInitialize(self.audioUnit);
    [self hasError:status:__FILE__:__LINE__];

    NSLog(@"Started");

}

//For now, this just copies the buffer to self.audioBuffer
-(void)processBuffer: (AudioBufferList*) audioBufferList
{
    AudioBuffer sourceBuffer = audioBufferList->mBuffers[0];

    // we check here if the input data byte size has changed
    if (_audioBuffer.mDataByteSize != sourceBuffer.mDataByteSize) {
        // clear old buffer
        free(self.audioBuffer.mData);

        // assing new byte size and allocate them on mData
        _audioBuffer.mDataByteSize = sourceBuffer.mDataByteSize;
        _audioBuffer.mData = malloc(sourceBuffer.mDataByteSize);
}

// copy incoming audio data to the audio buffer
memcpy(self.audioBuffer.mData, audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
}

#pragma mark - Error handling

-(void)hasError:(int)statusCode:(char*)file:(int)line 
{
    if (statusCode) {
        printf("Error Code responded %d in file %s on line %d\n", statusCode, file, line);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

@end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: side note: you should not perform objc messaging in realtime audio contexts (your render callback)

Answer (score 3):

This type of question comes up somewhat frequently, so I once wrote a [mini-tutorial on this subject](http://teragonaudio.com/article/How-to-do-realtime-recording-with-effect-processing-on-iOS.html). However, this guide is really the nuts-and-bolts way to solve the problem, I now feel that a far more elegant way is to use the [Novocaine framework](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine), which takes a lot of the headache out of AudioUnit setup on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found a demo codes, maybe useful 4 U;

DEMO URL:https://github.com/JNYJdev/AudioUnit

OR

blog: http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                              UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {

// Because of the way our audio format (setup below) is chosen:
// we only need 1 buffer, since it is mono
// Samples are 16 bits = 2 bytes.
// 1 frame includes only 1 sample

AudioBuffer buffer;

buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2;
buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 );

// Put buffer in a AudioBufferList
AudioBufferList bufferList;
bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;

// Then:
// Obtain recorded samples

OSStatus status;

status = AudioUnitRender([iosAudio audioUnit], 
                         ioActionFlags, 
                         inTimeStamp, 
                         inBusNumber, 
                         inNumberFrames, 
                         &bufferList);
checkStatus(status);

// Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
// Process the new data
[iosAudio processAudio:&bufferList];

// release the malloc'ed data in the buffer we created earlier
free(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData);

return noErr;
```

}